# Create a custom sugar_3.js file for an upgrade safe customization

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've been working on a bug related to the file sugar_3.js but since its a core file it will not be upgrade safe and I'm looking for a way of creating a custom js field that may overwrite some functions.

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my questions instead of just downvoting without any helpful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your SuiteCRM instance root

`touch custom/themes/SuiteP/js/style.js && echo "console.log('test custom js file on SuiteP theme or any othe better and fun message');" > custom/themes/SuiteP/js/style.js`

Go to the studio and make a Repair and Rebuild.

Check it out with `CTRL+SHIFT+i` on Chrome browser

If it worked copy all code from the file you need and then change it to your heart content.

Good luck